# What is the correct term for $\nabla\phi$? Co-vector or 1-form or both?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, differentiation, notation, vector-fields

In the olden days, $\nabla\phi$ was used to be called a *covariant vector* (Weinberg used this language in his book *Gravitation & Cosmology*). But this terminology is considered bad for several reasons and is now being slowly abandoned by physicists. In modern language, $\nabla\phi$ is called a *covector*, and $\partial\phi/\partial x^i$ is called the *$i$th component of a covector*. I hope I used the terms correctly so far in this context. However, here comes the confusing bit.

When I was reading vector spaces, I found that the terms covector and 1-form interchangeably (see *An Introduction to Algebraic Structures by Palash B. Pal*). IIRC, Goldstein's book on Classical Mechanics also refers to $\partial\phi/\partial x^i$ as the 1-form. Therefore, I thought that the covector $\partial\phi/\partial x^i$ is the same as the *1-form*. But while reading *Roger Penrose*'s *Roads to Reality* I found that he refers to $d\phi$ given by $$d\phi=\sum_i\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i}dx^i$$ as the 1-form. I'll be glad if someone can tell me the difference between a covector and a 1-form (in particular, w.r.t. my example).

Comment: *"...used to be called a covariant vector... is called a covector."* These are just synonyms. One is an abbreviation of the other.

Answer (score 3):

First, a quick review of terminology and notation; the answers to your questions will follow.

**Linear Algebra**

Vectors, covectors, and tensors are objects which arise in linear algebra, and do not require differential geometry to define. Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $\mathbb K$ (usually $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). The set of linear maps $V\rightarrow \mathbb K$ is denoted $V^*$ and is a vector space in its own right, where for any $\varphi,\chi\in V^*$ and $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb K$ we define
$$\big(\alpha \varphi + \beta \chi\big)(v) = \alpha \varphi(v) + \beta\chi(v)\tag{1}$$
for all $v\in V$.

The vector space $V^*$ is called the (algebraic) *dual space* to $V$, and elements of $V^*$ are called *dual vectors* or *covectors*. A $(p,q)$-tensor is a multilinear map which eats $p$ covectors and $q$ vectors and returns an element of $\mathbb K$. Because a covector is a linear map which eats 1 vector, we may identify the space of covectors with the space of $(0,1)$-tensors.

**Differential Geometry**

Given a smooth manifold $M$, let $C^\infty(M)$ denote the space of smooth functions from $M\rightarrow \mathbb R$. A *tangent vector field* $\mathbf X$ is a linear map from $C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ which obeys the Leibniz rule
$$\mathbf X(f g) = \mathbf X(f) g + f \mathbf X(g)\tag{2}$$
Given a coordinate system $x = (x^1,x^2,\ldots)$ defined on some open patch $U\subseteq M$, the action of any vector field $\mathbf X$ on a function $f\in C^\infty(M)$ can be expressed as
$$\mathbf X(f) = X^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\tag{3}$$
For that reason, we can simply identify $\mathbf X = X^i \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$ and call $X^i$ the components of $\mathbf X$ with respect to the basis $\{\partial/\partial x^i\}$.  Recalling our linear algebra, we define *covector fields* as linear maps which eat vector fields and spit out $\mathbb R$-numbers; the notation we use for the dual basis to $\{\partial/\partial x^i\}$ is $\{\mathrm dx^i\}$. In other words, we define $\{\mathrm dx^i\}$ to be the basis for the space of covector fields such that $\mathrm dx^i (\partial/\partial x^j) = \delta^i_j$.

Just as before, we also define $(p,q)$-tensor fields as multilinear maps which eat $p$ covector fields and $q$ vector fields and spit out $\mathbb R$-numbers. Just as before, the space of covector fields can be identified with the space of $(0,1)$-tensor fields.

**Differential Forms**

For reasons which will become increasingly clear with more study, the space of smooth, totally-antisymmetric $(0,k)$-tensor fields turns out to be extremely interesting in its own right. Such objects are called *(differential) $k$-forms*. All $(0,0)$-tensor fields (i.e. scalar fields, which belong to $C^\infty(M)$) and $(0,1)$-tensors (i.e. covector fields) are taken to be $0$-forms and $1$-forms by default, since anitsymmetry is only meaningful for maps with $\geq 2$ arguments.

One of the primary reasons that differential forms are interesting is that they come with an intrinsic notion of differentiation which does not require any additional structure (in the form of Christoffel symbols, or more generally a *connection*) to define - namely, the *exterior derivative* $\mathrm d$ which maps $k$-forms to $(k+1)$-forms. To answer your question, it suffices to say that the exterior derivative of a 0-form (i.e. a scalar field) $\phi$ is given by the 1-form (i.e. covector field)
$$\mathrm d\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} \mathrm dx^i$$

**Vector $\leftrightarrow$ Covector Duality**

Given a non-degenerate $(0,2)$-tensor field $g$ (for metric manifolds, we typically use the metric tensor), one can map a vector field $\mathbf X$ to a covector field $\mathbf X^\flat = g(\cdot, \mathbf X)$ where $\cdot$ denotes an empty slot. The components of $\mathbf X^\flat$ are given by $(X^\flat)_i = g_{ij} X^j$. Defining $\tilde g^{ij}$ to be the matrix inverse of the $g_{ij}$'s, we can also map covector fields $\boldsymbol \omega$ to vector fields $\boldsymbol \omega^\sharp$ which have components $(\omega^\sharp)^i = \tilde g^{ij} \omega_j$.

---

Now to answer your questions.

1. Because covector fields are $(0,1)$-tensor fields and $(0,1)$-tensor fields are 1-forms, covector fields and 1-forms are the same thing. Note that strictly speaking a covector (rather than a covector *field*) is not the same thing, but in the literature and in common parlance it is very common to drop the word "*field*" from the discussion and to simply say that 1-forms are covectors.
2. The gradient of a scalar field $\phi$ is naturally the covector field/1-form $\mathrm d\phi$, which (in a coordinate system $x=(x^1,x^2,\ldots)$) takes the form $\mathrm d\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} \mathrm dx^i$. $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i}$ is the $i^{th}$ component of the covector field/1-form $\mathrm d\phi$ with respect to the basis $\{\mathrm dx^i\}$, which is itself dual to the vector field basis $\{\partial/\partial x^i\}$. However ...
3. Given a metric tensor $g$ (or another suitable object), it is possible to define the *vector* field gradient of a scalar to be $(\mathrm d\phi)^\sharp$, whose components are $\tilde g^{ij} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i}$. I tend to call this object $\mathrm{grad}(\phi)$. **This** is the object which coincides with what is normally written $\nabla \phi$.

The distinction between $\nabla \phi \equiv (\mathrm d\phi)^\sharp$ and $\mathrm d\phi$ is often swept under the rug. The former is a vector field while the latter is a covector field. In Cartesian coordinates, the metric components are given by $g_{ij} = \tilde g^{ij} = \mathrm{diag}(1,1,\ldots)$ and so $\nabla \phi$ and $\mathrm d\phi$ have the same components; however, this fails to be true in curvilinear coordinates.  In plane polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, for example, one has
$$g_{ij} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & r^2} \qquad \tilde g^{ij} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{r^2}}$$

and so

$$\mathrm d\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \mathrm dr + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} \mathrm d\theta \qquad \nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{r^2}} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$

Expressed in the normalized bases $\{\epsilon^r,\epsilon^\theta\} = \left\{dr, r\mathrm d\theta\right\}$ and $\{e_r, e_\theta\} = \left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\}$, we have that

$$\mathrm d\phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\epsilon^r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} \epsilon^\theta \qquad \nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} e_r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} e_\theta$$

where we see that once we return to an orthonormal frame, the numerical values of the components coincide (but of course, this is a basis-dependent statement). These expressions should be familiar from [the standard multivariable calculus literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

Comment: I think it would save a lot of confusion if differential forms and abstract vector spaces were more systematically integrated into the curriculum at the calculus III level. Students spend 4 years thinking of $\nabla \phi$ as a vector only to understand at the grad level that they were sort of being lied to (not told the whole truth is better). Maybey its just not possible to squeeze it in.

Comment: oh and this brings up the other annoying notational issue that $\nabla$ also is wonderfully used to denote the connection in the tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold, and its extension to the full tensor algebra, where by definition for smooth functions $\phi:M\to\Bbb{R}$, one has $\nabla\phi:=d\phi= \mathscr{L}_{(\cdot)}\phi$, rather than the metrically related vector field $\text{grad}_g(\phi)$. So, yet another wonderful conflict of notation. Differential geometry truly is the *study of things invariant under change of notation*.

Comment: Also, your normalization at the end is wrong. It should be $\epsilon^{\theta}=r\,d\theta$ (since $g=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2= (dr)^2+(r\,d\theta)^2$ so $\{dr,r\,d\theta\}$ is the orthonormal coframe) and $e_{\theta}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

No real geometric difference. For example as you say ${\partial\phi\over \partial x^i}$ is the ith component of the covector. The two ideas coincide if you understand $dx^i$ as a basis for the one-form or covector space. Here he has written the covector out as a sum over basis vectors instead of a list of components. Basically, for every vector space in which contravariant vectors or simply, vectors reside; with basis ${e_i}$, there exists a dual space in which resides covariants or covectors, or one-forms with dual basis, ${dx^i}$ such that:$$e_i\; dx^j=\delta_i^j.$$ Where $\delta_i^j$ is the Kronecker delta. As a tangible example, one might consider a vector, $d\vec x$ that can be written in terms of its basis as:$$d\vec x=dx^i\;e_i.$$ And one might consider a covector or one-form $dx$ that can be written in terms of its basis:$$dx={\partial x\over \partial x^i}\; dx^i.$$ In the first example one is consiering an ordinary displacement vector or differential, however, in the second; one is working with an *exterior derivative*. One could therefore write the work done as an inner product:$$\langle d\vec x,dx\rangle=dx^i\; e_i\;\;{\partial x\over \partial x^i}\;dx^i={\partial x\over \partial x^i}dx^i\;(e_i\;dx^i)={\partial x\over \partial x^i}dx^i=\nabla x\cdot d\vec x.$$ A no doubt familiar scalar quantity corresponding to work done when x is an exact differential.
In short, it is an abstract way of formulating ordinary physics in terms of tensor fields on manifolds using geometric ideas like the tangent space and cotangent space defined locally at some point on the manifold.

Comment: I don't understand how $dx^i$ is a basis. Can you elaborate? As far as I understand, $dx^i$'s are components of $d\vec{x}$ i.e., $d\vec{x}=\sum_i dx^i \vec{e}_i$ where $\{\vec{e}_i\}$ is a basis in the original vector space.

Comment: I have added some detail in my post, hope it helps. For a brief yet cogent introduction to tensors and differential geometry one should see the third edition of Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics*, viz. chapter 7. Keeping in mind that whenever Goldstein writes, $\omega^i$ he means what most more modern and mathematically inclined authors mean by $dx^i$. Sorry, I just realized you already seen Goldstein, but perhaps the suggestion substitution suggestion might help.

Comment: One has to loose the idea of thinking of $\nabla \phi$ as simply the components of a gradient vector; it *can* be understood that way, but it is not the only way. Equally one might understand it as a *covector*; a vector in the algebraic sense, but with a co-basis; dual to, and in the place of the usual one for vectors.

Answer (score 0):

First, an element of a vector space $V$ is called a vector. Whilst an element of its dual space, $V*$ is called a covector.

Although its quite common that $\nabla\phi$ is called a *covector*, it is in fact a smooth covector field. This is equivalently known as a 1-form.